# Git diff between current branch and it's remote branch ignoring commits merged from master

Tags: git, diff

I can diff current branch with it's remote branch using `git diff branch remote-branch`

But how can I ignore changes merged from master to remote-branch?

Answer (score 1):

The `git diff` command only compares two *commits*.<sup>1</sup>  A commit *is* a thing indexed by its commit number—its hash ID—that stores a snapshot and metadata.  So you run `git diff` and give it two commit numbers, e.g., `git diff a123456 b789abc`.  Or, you give it two *branch names* like `branch` and `origin/branch`, or `branch` and `remote-branch`; Git turns those *names* into raw commit hash IDs, and then does the same diff.

So:

> ... how can I ignore changes merged from master to remote-branch?

You can't.  You're going to compare two *commits*.

What if, instead of comparing the commit named by the name `branch` vs the commit named by the name `remote-branch`, we *leave the second commit alone* but take the *first* commit and *change it*, so as to incorporate "changes merged from master".  That is, we:

1. Create a *new* (but temporary) branch, pointing to the commit identified by the name `branch`, so that we start with the same snapshot as in the last commit on branch `branch`.
2. Make *changes* and make a *new commit*.  The changes we make bring this up to date.
3. Compare this new commit, on *this* branch, to the unchanged commit on `remote-branch`.

If that isn't suitable, consider the other obvious alternative: keep the commit found by the name `branch` untouched, but make a new, temporary branch that *starts out* using the same snapshot—in fact, the same *commit*—as that identified by `remote-branch`, but then makes a new commit in which the "changes merged from master" are *rolled back* (perhaps using `git revert`, which does this sort of thing).

This way, we're back to two comparable commits: one of them is the one you were going to compare before, and the other is the one you were going to compare it to, but with some set of changes rolled-back.

**These methods are not perfect but they are as close as you can get with simple Git commands and the setup you described.**  To get a perfect comparison, you'd have to make sure that `remote-branch` never has those changes rolled *into* it in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup>That's not right: it compares two commits (to each other), or one commit (to something that's not a commit).  It can even compare two non-commit things, such as two trees that are both outside the repository.  But the point here is that you have to already *have both commits*, when your desire is to compare the two commits.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer!

You may think that task to ignore merged commits in diff is odd. But when you want to see difference between revisions during merge request review, commits from master are not interesting for you. Ok, there is a way to use temporarily branch. But may be range-diff may help in it somehow?

Comment: It's not particularly *odd*, it's just the case that *you cannot do it* without first performing some additional commits or other work. That's because Git cannot show you the differences between files that you have not yet made. Range-diff is very different: it compares multiple separate diffs, each of which compares snapshots.

Comment: I think about different ways to solve my original problem. Possibly, range-diff between (diff branch master) and (remote-branch master) will show only real differences?

Comment: You'd need to run the range diff on the right range. Given that there *is* a merge commit somewhere in the `origin/master` chain (at the tip? before the tip?), you will need to make sure that the range diff doesn't try to use this merge. That could be tricky. If the merge is right at the tip, it's not tricky: just exclude the tip commit entirely. But in that particular case, you can just do the simple "diff two existing commits" with that same pre-tip-commit, since it's the commit "before the merge" that I suggested after the bold sentence in the original answer.